# more than one modal in one page where some of the modals are carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, simplemodal

I have a page with several buttons, when each button is clicked a different modal pops up. Some of the modals are carousels, the code I have works but for only one of the carousels, when I have more than one I get extra empty slides on all the carousels. So I'm guessing my code is counting all the slides from all the carousels together. Im trying to have write something where it says if this modal is clicked then get the slides from the clicked modal only but Im struggling with that.

These are the bits of relevant code:

```html
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalOne"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalB"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
<button class="button" data-modal="#modalC"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>
 
<!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="modalA" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 
 <div class= "mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   
   <h4>Title</h4>
      <p> content </p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
   <h4 Title</h4>
   <p> content </p>
   
 </div>
  
    <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal B -->
 <div id="modalB" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 
 <div class="mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
 </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<!-- The Modal C -->
 <div id="modalC" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span>
 <div class="mySlides">
   <img class="gif" src="" width="100" height="100"  >
   
   <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
  
 
 <div class="mySlides">
  
   <h4></h4>
   <p></p>
 </div>
 <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</div>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
 <script>
//Carousel
 
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
 showDivs(slideIndex += n); 
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
 for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     /*dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");*/
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  /*dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";*/
}

  </script>

 
<script>
//Display corresponding modal of letter that is clicked 
 
$(".button").on("click", function() {
   var modal = $(this).data("modal");
   $(modal).show();
   document.body.classList.add("modal-open");  
 
});
  

  
//Close modal when "x" is clicked or when area outside modal is clicked
$(".modal").on("click", function(e) {
   var className = e.target.className;
   if(className === "modal" || className === "close"){
   $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
   document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
  }
});
  

  
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you don't have correct "<" for the ending tag on the buttons.

Comment: Yes sorry I think I did that by accident when I copied the code over it is correct in my actual code <button class="button" data-modal="#modalOne"><img id="myImg" src=""></button>

Comment: hmm... I'm thinking you could then instead just have one hidden modal that you just insert html into then, using the .innerHTML thinger majig

Comment: How would I do that? Would I not have the same problem with different ones having different number of pages?